# How do I write a string equals function that allows for at most one letter of not being equal?

Tags: ruby

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I want to write a function that will compare strings and declare them "equal" if all characters match or if both strings have the same number of characters and all characters except one match.  So for example, by that logic, these strings would match

```
wonder
wander
```

Above the only difference is the "o" and the "a".  These would also match

```
zzz
zza
```

But these would not match

```
abcdef
abcdef1
```

because the above do not have the same amount of characters.  How do I write such a function?

Comment: Can you think of a way to make an array with `true` where the strings’ characters are equal and `false` where they aren’t, like `[true, true, false]` for `'zzz'` and `'zza'`?

Comment: The first guard is easy `return false unless str1.size == str2.size`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for your given cases:

```
def str_equal(a, b)
  a == b || (a.size == b.size && a.chars.map.with_index{|c, i| c == b[i]}.count(false) == 1)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Ryan's and nicooga's comments, plus the necessary missing parts:

**Updated** using meta’s advice

```
def close_enough(str1, str2)
    return false unless str1.size == str2.size

    mismatches = str1
        .chars
        .zip(str2.chars)
        .count{ |(x, y)| x != y }

    (mismatches <= 1)
end
```

Comment: You can improve that a bit by doing `matches = str1.chars.zip(str2.chars).count{ |(x, y)| x == y }` (no need for map, then count - just count it immediatelly)

Comment: That's alot of intermediary `Array`s

Answer (score 1):

When the two strings differ in size or differ by more than one character, the method below returns `false`. I designed the method to short-circuit the calculations as soon as it is determined that `false` is to be returned, but still have an efficient determination of a `true` return value.

```
def at_most_one_character_different?(str1, str2)
  str1.size == str2.size &&
    (str1 == str2 || str1.size.times.one? { |i| str1[i] != str2[i] })
end

at_most_one_character_different? "", ""               #=> true
at_most_one_character_different? "humpty", "humpty"   #=> true
at_most_one_character_different? "humpty", "dumpty"   #=> true
at_most_one_character_different? "humpty", "dumbty"   #=> false
at_most_one_character_different? "humpty", "humptye"  #=> false
```

Comment: I like the short circuit although it might read better as `str1 == str2 || str1.size.times.one? {|i| str1[i] != str2[i]}` and it cuts the footprint down to 2 lines. Additionally you are the only person that did not create unnecessary intermediary `Arrays`

Comment: @engineersmnky, that does read well but of course does not short-circuit.

Comment: it does short circuit just like `all?` and `any?` and `none?` https://repl.it/LWxC that's why it is perfect for this solution :)

Comment: @engineersmnky, you are right, of course.  That's an improvement, so I edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that there are no unicode or other multi-byte charactes you can get a small performance boost by comparing bytes instead of the actual characters. (Just because all the other quality answers were taken)

```
 def at_most_one_byte_diff?(str1, str2)
   return false if str1.size != str2.size
   str1 == str2 || str1.each_byte.with_index.one? { |b,i| b != str2.getbyte(i) }
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass difference count as parameter:

```
def str_compare_by_diff_count(a, b, diff_count)
  (a.size == b.size) && a.chars.select.with_index { |v, i| v != b[i] }.count <= diff_count
end

str_compare_by_diff_count("wonder", "wander", 1)   #=> true
str_compare_by_diff_count("wonder", "wandor", 1)   #=> false
str_compare_by_diff_count("wonder", "wandor", 2)   #=> true
str_compare_by_diff_count("wonder", "wanbor", 2)   #=> false
str_compare_by_diff_count("wonder", "wanderr", 1)  #=> false
```